# Odoo check field in other module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How can we check in method if field is empty. How this code should look correctly.

i hope try to made my point clear.

```
def method(self, vals):
    if vals.get("field" == empty)
    use my logic
    if not empty use data that was already there.
    and if that field is in other model , how can i reach it.
```

Comment: what is the type of vals every one here think that is dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def method(self):
    if vals.get("field_name", False): 
        # Code if is not empty
    else:  
        # Code if is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, in which first check if key is in vals or not. if key is available then check value is set or not.

```
def method(self, vals):
    if vals.has_key('field') and not vals.get('field',False):
        print "if logic"
    else:
        print "else logic"
```

If field is not empty and **field is in other model** then you should try with **active_model**.

You can pass **active_model** in context from calling method, based on that **you can browse record or do other operation**.

Ex:

```
def method(self, vals):
    if vals.has_key('field') and not vals.get('field',False):
        print "if logic"
    else:
        model=self._context.get('active_model')
        self.env[model].browse(model)
        print "else logic"

self.with_context({'active_model':'model'}).method(vals)
```

Using **with_context** user can pass **context** & based on context value you can easily get active model dynamically.

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def method(self, vals):
    if not vals.get('field'):
        #if empty use your logic
    else:
        #if not empty use data that was already there.
        #to print field value:
        print vals['field']

            #and if that field is in other model , how can i reach it.
        you may reach it by search that field in other model.
```